# Sending ping packets Stealthily

Tags: ping, kali-linux

I have a task to send data "stealthily" in a ping packet between 2 kali machines. Does this have to do with "stealth mode". Is there a config file I need to edit to run in stealth mode.

Answer (score 1):

An ICMP packet consists of a header and a payload. With a ping packet, the payload is optional, but ping utilities will let you set a length parameter to make a packet an arbitrary size.  Often used to test MTU and fragmentation.

The data that is used in the payload in these cases can be anything - it is often the characters a-z repeating, and so it can be used to carry real data while looking like an ordinary ping packet.  Instead of `abcd...` it could just as well contain `this is a secret message` and still be a valid packet.

There are vpn clients available that will use ping as a transport for encrypted data.  These are sometimes used to bypass firewalls, where ping is permitted but little else.

Comment: Understood. Why is it used too test MTU and fragmentation?

Comment: @gerardhorgan It is just a quick and dirty way to do it, and ubiquitous, as most ping utilities let you set dont-fragment and the packet size.  So if you have a network with multiple MTUs in the path (like with a VPN) you can determine the maximum transmissible unit along the path with ping alone.